# Customization of Nordic countries in sitecore with same locale code and different querystring

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7

There is a weird requirement in my sitecore website.

Normal functional flow is : I hit website using locale for ex: "en-us" and when I close tab and open it the website is in "en-us" and if I hit some other target for ex: "en-gb" it takes me into "en-gb" website. This is working perfectly as per cookies set.

Problem is with nordic countries i.e Norway, Sweden, Denamark, Finland etc. These countries have single locale code i.e "se-no" and I am just appending querystring to specify nordic countries i.e se-no/webname/home?country=norway.

Since they are having same locale code so every time I request for /nordic/pages/search.aspx everytime it takes me into startitem of dropdown list of nordic countries i.e Denmark as per dropdownlist.

What I want is when I hit /nordic/pages/search.aspx than my countrychange code not to work and it keeps me into context of previous environment .

For example if I hit /nordic/pages/search.aspx than it takes me into /se-no/denmark but if I am in se-no/norway than I want to be in /se-no/norway intead of default nordic country i.e denmark.

I know this is huge to read and tried everything to tell you guys exact situation, shoot me any question which is require for clarification. I just need to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "single locale code" for nordic countries; there's `nb-NO` (Bokmål, Norway), `nn-NO` (Nynorsk, Norway), `sv-SE` (Swedish, Sweden), `fi-FI` (Finnish, Finland), `da-DK` (Danish, Denmark). There's also several cases of other combos; `sv-FI` (Swedish, Finland), `fi-SE` (Finnish, Sweden) due to historic reasons. There are some places in Sweden where over 10% of inhabitants speak Finnish.

Note that Norway have two written languages; Bokmål and Nynorsk, and the official language differ between municipalities. Bokmål is the largest one (over 80% of Norway) and is probably your target language. Note that the `no-NO` locale seen is ambiguous, and often an alias for `nb-NO`. Use the specific one, `nb-NO`/`nn-NO`, and make sure your translation company translates to Bokmål/Nynorsk, and not "norwegian", just to be sure.

I would say that you've implemented your locale codes for these regions wrong, `se-NO` (Sami, Norway) does exists, but it's probably not what you want. There's about 30k native speakers of Sami, spread out over northern Norway, Sweden and Finland. The Sami language is in turn split into several sublanguages, some of them with less than 50 native speakers, about as many as those being able to speak Klingon fluently.